# Django: Redirect to the referring page (not the current form) when an UpdateView fails validation and is then Canceled?

Tags: django, redirect

My Django application allows a user to navigate to an Update Form (UpdateView) from multiple locations in the application.  Currently, if the form is saved successfully I can redirect without a problem to the referring page by saving request.META.HTTP_REFERER in a hidden field in the template and retrieving it in form_valid.  I can leverage the HTTP_REFERER data in MOST, but not ALL cases.  One of those is the following scenario:

1. My user navigates to the FORM A from Page X (HTTP_REFERER is set to Page X)
2. FORM A is submitted and does not pass validation (HTTP_REFERER is now set to FORM A instead of Page X because indeed it has self-refered.)
3. My user clicks Cancel (they are redirected back to FORM A instead of Page X)

Is there a way to capture the Cancel event before it is processed and perform some logic so my user gets referred back to Page X instead of being stuck in the form?